# Sign CAdES using BouncyCastle using JAVA

Tags: java, bouncycastle

According to several posts I've found out it's now possible to perform CAdES using BouncyCastle but there is hardly any documentation on the topic.

For starters I want to perform CAdES-BES without any optional signed attributes on a file with a file based certificate.

---

In response to dander:

I have something that might be helpful, you have your SignerInformation, you need to extend it, first you need to create an attribute from the timestamp, I'll assume you already have a TimeStampResponse as tspResp

```
TimeStampToken token = tsresp.getTimeStampToken();

Attribute timeStamp = new Attribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signatureTimeStampToken, new DERSet(ASN1Object.fromByteArray(token.getEncoded())));
```

Then you need to extend your SignerInformation

```
AttributeTable unsigned = signerInformation.getUnsignedAttributes();
Hashtable<ASN1ObjectIdentifier, Attribute> unsignedAttrHash = null;
if (unsigned == null) {
    unsignedAttrHash = new Hashtable<ASN1ObjectIdentifier, Attribute>();
} else {
    unsignedAttrHash = signerInformation.getUnsignedAttributes().toHashtable();
}

unsignedAttrHash.put(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signatureTimeStampToken, signatureTimeStamp);

SignerInformation newsi = SignerInformation.replaceUnsignedAttributes(si, new AttributeTable(
        unsignedAttrHash));
```

I think that's about it.

Here is how I got the signin-certificate attribute

---

```
Attribute signingCertificateAttribute;
MessageDigest dig = MessageDigest.getInstance(DigestAlgorithm().getName(),
    new BouncyCastleProvider());

byte[] certHash = dig.digest(SigningCertificate().getEncoded());

if (DigestAlgorithm() == DigestAlgorithm.SHA1) {
    SigningCertificate sc = new SigningCertificate(new ESSCertID(certHash));

    signingCertificateAttribute = new Attribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signingCertificate, new DERSet(sc));

} else {
    ESSCertIDv2 essCert = new ESSCertIDv2(new AlgorithmIdentifier(DigestAlgorithm().getOid()), certHash);
    SigningCertificateV2 scv2 = new SigningCertificateV2(new ESSCertIDv2[] { essCert });

    signingCertificateAttribute =  new Attribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signingCertificateV2, new DERSet(scv2));
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the information, did you implement the "signing-certificate" (or signing-certificate-v2) signed attribute? I have trouble with including it, do you have any specific code for that part?

Comment: I use signing-certificate in the case of sha1, elsewhere I use signing-certificate-v2, I'll add some code

Comment: Hi, just a quick question that I cannot get my head around. What data do you send out to the timestamping server. I am currently sending CMSignedData.getEncoded() and it shows that there is a timestamp on the signature, but it shows as invalid :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CAdES is an extension of CMS (aka PKCS7), which is possible to do with BouncyCastle. [RFC5126](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5126) contains everything needed for a CAdES signature, also, I recommend lookup info on ASN.1 since most of the parts are described in that format.

I am currently in hunt for the same answer you are looking for and found that the book [Beginning Cryptography with Java by David Hook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0764596330) gives a lot of detailed information you might need.

Comment: We already developed a wrapper around BouncyCastle and a third party project to sign and verify documents using CAdES-BES/CAdES-T/CAdES-C, it was built for a customer and we don't plan on releasing it as opensource (yet anyway), with that said if I you need any help let me know.

Comment: @AndresSM: Well, my biggest problem is that, how can I extend a CMS to become a Cades-T, if you have any kind of source snippets, that would be a huge help!

Answer (score 3):

Useful code could be found on "https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/"

Take a look on [CAdESProfileBES.java](https://joinup.ec.europa.eu/svn/sd-dss/trunk/apps/dss/dss-document/src/main/java/eu/europa/ec/markt/dss/signature/cades/CAdESProfileBES.java).

Someone put the same code on [Fork of the original SD - Digital Signature Service](https://github.com/latraccia).