# the signature includes en embedded timeStamp but it could not be verified

Tags: pdf, digital-signature, bouncycastle, pdfbox, adobe-reader

I've just added timestamp to my pdf. signature is valid. timestamp token is correct too (I checked already). but adobe reader tells me that **"signature includes an embedded timestamp but it could not be veridied".**

[image]

```
AttributeTable unsigned = signerInformation.getUnsignedAttributes();
Hashtable<ASN1ObjectIdentifier, Attribute> unsignedAttrHash = null;
if (unsigned == null) {
    unsignedAttrHash = new Hashtable<ASN1ObjectIdentifier, Attribute>();
} else {
    unsignedAttrHash = signerInformation.getUnsignedAttributes().toHashtable();
}

unsignedAttrHash.put(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.id_aa_signatureTimeStampToken, signatureTimeStamp);

SignerInformation newSignertInformation = SignerInformation.replaceUnsignedAttributes(si, new AttributeTable(unsignedAttrHash));
```

I fount  [this  code at stackowerflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13675583/sign-cades-using-bouncycastle-using-java)  it works. it's really correct code.   finally I have  new SignerInformationStore and   new CMS Signed Data   like this

```
CMSSignedData.replaceSigners(oldCMSSignedData, newSignerStore);
```

but maybe something is missing in my PDF? certificate or something like that?

[that's sample pdf](https://www.dropbox.com/s/piv6ilb20zngcj2/original-signed.pdf)

Comment: Hi! I am struggling with the same problem you had. Can you explain to me, what kind of data you've sent to the timestampping service to retrieve the correct message imprint? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The message imprint in the signature-time-stamp seems to be not correct. It is expected to have the SHA256 of the signature value in this message imprint.

SHA256 of the signature value:

```
1b4532052d612ca32ae96b9a8e7aa6d64ae6c69dc00e1b7b31394ac3b54c4049
```

The message imprint in the time-stamp token:

```
E3B0C44298FC1C149AFBF4C8996FB92427AE41E4649B934CA495991B7852B855
```

Comment: ok. I'll see if this is solution. :-) P.S which software do you use to see that?

Comment: I'm a Cryptolog employee and I used our software [Serenity](http://www.cryptolog.com/en/products/server-products/serenity-electronic-signature-validation) to validate the signature.

Comment: I have similar issue but couldn't understand the solution

Comment: @Ibrahim You have to first get the signature for the digest of your byterange from your digital signature provider API or whatever you're using, then you need to SHA256 digest that signature and send that as the digest for the timestamp request.